# Finding concavity:$ f'(x)=2\cos x+\sin2x$

Tags: calculus

"Suppose there is a function $f$ defined on $[0,2\pi]$ where the first derivative, $f'(x)=2\cos  x+\sin2x$"

a. State intervals where $f$ is concave up.

b. Find inflection pts.

So far, I found the 2nd derivative.

$f"(x)=-2\sin x+2\cos2x$.

Now I am just confused how to find the zeros.

Comment: You know that by finding the second derivative, you can find the critical points for the graph to provide a foundation first.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that at by law of the second derivative, when the graph concavity is concave up, the condition is that $f\prime\prime>0$, and with concave down, the condition is that $f\prime\prime<0$. For the concavity, you should be able to go from there. The inflection point is where $f\prime\prime=0$. so that means that where is $f\prime\prime(0)=?$. Then you do this:

$$f\prime\prime(?)=-2\sin(?)+2\cos(2(?))=0$$

I think with this, you can figure the rest out. This site is not for answers to be give so good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sufficient reputation point to post a comment.

For the zeros of $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$, you can use $cos(2x)=1-2sin^2(x)$. This gives you a second-order equation in $sin(x)$.